# SmartGwt with hibernate for database connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, smartgwt

I am using **eclipse indigo**.I want to use **hibernate with smartgwt**  [smart gwt showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/showcase/#hibernateAutoDerivation)

I have a grid so want data from database using hibernate datasource(ds) like smartgwt    showcase EE. I don't understand how to connect to database using hibernate(ds) and get data from table.

Comment: You create a configuration file and mapping file?

Comment: yes according to structure i know create ds.xml and server.properties but i don't understand how to connect with hibernate. eclipse need another plugins ar not?

Comment: Yes, You have to download plugins. You can use this as reference.http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-install-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-ide/

Comment: i am able to use hibernate but how hibernate use with smart gwt?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but since it is not answered here goes,

The thing is table is on the client side so you first have to move your data to your server end and do the hibernate stuff there. To achieve that I would suggest a custom datasource using gwt-rpc. You can the code here.

https://code.google.com/p/smartgwt-extensions/

Once you have that working you can do your regular hibernate stuff on the server side.